# how to change written language from `en` to `fa` when entering input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a few input box. i want change language when user entered one of the input box.
and change when entered to another input box.
Is there a method to this problem?
Thanks

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CityName, new { placeholder = " " , Lang = "fa-IR" })
```

Comment: We don't write up code here at SO, so post a minimal working code snippet so we have with what to work

Comment: Do you want to change translations made in razor or do you simply want to change an HTML attribute in the textbox tag? This can only be done in javascript.

Comment: Please show the html that this code generates and show your javascript code that you have.

Comment: I did not write Javascript code
And I know that is possible with Javascript
But how?

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Comment: excuse me. I am sincerely grateful your answer .
I was involved in another part of the project and could not give your answer
I wanted to change the writing language. But this did not happen

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to change the website language from EN to FA by letting the user type something into an input tag? If I understood correctly, that can be done by listening for an event on the input tag with javascript.

When the event is triggered you can inject the proper language text inside the HTML elements by using some javascript logic.

```
$("yourInputElementInEnglish").on("eventTrigger", function(){

  yourHTMLElement.html("text in english");

});
```